# Trying to run live usb of 16.04 Intel NUC5PPYU

Tags: 64-bit, live-usb, bug-reporting, livedvd

I already have 14.04 running and would like to try 16.04 as live usb however it only gets part way through and hangs. My system is an Intel NUC5PPYH 64bit. I have already tried running a 14.04 DVD
to make sure it's not the computer and that works as a try before you install.I'm reluctant to try to do a complete install of 16.04
as it would seem to be software related.

Comment: look at this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1512995) . Also, do you have the [latest updates](http://drivers.softpedia.com/blog/Intel-s-NUC5PPYH-and-NUC5CPYH-NUC-Kits-Receive-Drivers-Download-Now-480165.shtml) ?

Comment: I found a solution on this computer . Go to the bios press F2 and set the advanced option to Linux  . Then reboot press F10 and choose the USB device you want to load 16.04  from.

Comment: Great. You should answer your own question in the answer space and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some options on the bios setup.

While the nuc is starting, press F2 to enter the BIOS setup. Then follow this path:

```
BIOS > Boot > Boot Configuration > OS Selection > set Linux
```

This fixed it. With older kernels there is no need to do this.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521749 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1529353